# Audio and Video Streaming Issues with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg to stream a specific window on my computer. While the video works flawlessly, adding the audio is being problematic. Whenever I had audio (using `-f dshow`), the video's fps dramatically drops to 3 to 5 fps and a ton of dropped frames occur. Here is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -draw_mouse 0 -i title="MainWindow" -f dshow \
       -i audio="CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)" \
       -c:v mpeg2video -b:v 4000k -c:a aac -b:a 64k -f mpegts udp://localhost:1234
```

The audio doesn't seem clear also (like it sound somewhat garbleled). I have tried to split the video and audio and then combine them. When I combine the audio and video, I get a black and white screen with what looks like an old-fashioned image. (The window I am trying to record isn't recognizable). What is going on and how can I fix it?